# Classic ASP SAML 2.0 "Middleware"

Tags: php, authentication, asp-classic, saml, middleware

That's my need: my company run a web-application coded with classic asp. Now one of our customer want that application to use SSO with their own IdP using SAML 2.0. So I have to interface with that service to verify users credential and then granting access.

I search the web to know about SAML protocol and, as far as I understood, my web-app have to act as a Service Provider, but the SAML protocols and specs are quite complex.

So, that's the question: do you know any "middleware", Classic ASP or PHP based, that can help me dealing with this kind of authentication?

Thanks.

EDIT: googling around, I came across this one

https://onelogin.zendesk.com/entries/268420-saml-toolkit-for-php

Anyone knows it?

Comment: Have a look at http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html and the links inside it.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleSAMLPHP is a solid library, however, I would guess that it's far more than what you are looking for... It's an implementation with both SP and IdP code, and, while it has the name "simple" in it, is far more complex than what you need.

I would suggest you try looking at Kentor's open source stuff:
http://coding.abel.nu/2013/09/an-open-source-asp-net-saml2-service-provider/ It's pretty recent, and I've seen others use it successfully.

Comment: I think that the Saml2AuthenticationModule in Kentor.AuthServices can run with an asp classic site. Then it should be possible to use ordinary path restrictions in web.config for authorization. Thanks for mentioning our stuff by the way. Would love an e-mail with some info about others using it. Always nice to know if the code ends up valuable for others.

Comment: I have no experience with ASP.NET, can you address me to some Classic ASP example for this module, if any?

Comment: Luca, you're better off contacting Anders who made the comment on 4 Jan. He's the developer of the kit, and they have some samples right on the page I linked you to.

Comment: Problem is Andrew when you click that link the first line reads :
An Open Source ASP.NET SAML2 Service Provider

Which is why Luca said what he said ... its .NET

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your application has to act as a Service Provider.

Try [SimpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) Service Provider. I haven't used it personally for integration with an existing application, but seems it should work for you.

Please refer: http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.5/simplesamlphp-sp#section_6

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenAm's Fedlet library for .Net applications :
http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/10.1.0/dev-guide/index/chap-fedlet-dotnet.html

Comment: Luca asked for asp classic or php .. .NET is the opposite of that.